# Creating a record on a module when inserting on an other module

Tags: odoo

I want to create a record on inventory with quantity = 0 whenever I add a new record to products. Is it possible?
I have 2 modules like so :

```py
class productss(models.Model):
      _name = 'productss.productss'
      name = fields.Char()
      description = fields.Text()
      price =fields.Float()
class inventory(models.Model):
      _name = 'inventory.inventory'
      id_product = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='productss.productss')
      qte = fields.Integer(compute="_value_qte", store=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just override `productss.productss`'s `create()` and create an inventory record within:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, values)
    record = super().create(values)
    # create an inventory
    inv_values = {'id_product': record.id, 'qte': 0}
    self.env['inventory.inventory'].create(inv_values)
    return record
```

This code requires the "new" Odoo API (V8+) and Python3